# complicated sql query returns a result with empty tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have three empty tables

```
--
-- Tabellenstruktur für Tabelle `projects`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `projects` (
`id_project` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`id_plan` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`description` longtext NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id_project`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Tabellenstruktur für Tabelle `project_plans`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `project_plans` (
`id_plan` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`description` longtext NOT NULL,
`max_projects` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`max_member` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`max_filestorage` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '3221225472' COMMENT '3GB Speicherplatz',
PRIMARY KEY (`id_plan`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Tabellenstruktur für Tabelle `project_users`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `project_users` (
`id_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
`id_project` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

All these tables are empty but i get a result with my query?
my query:

```
SELECT
    A.id_plan,
    A.name AS plan_name,
    A.description AS plan_description,
    A.max_projects,
    A.max_member,
    A.max_filestorage,
    B.id_plan,
    B.name AS project_name,
    B.description AS project_description,
    C.id_user,
    C.id_project,
    COUNT(*) AS max_project_member
FROM
    ".$this->config_vars["projects_plans_table"]." AS A
LEFT JOIN
    ".$this->config_vars["projects_table"]." AS B
ON
    B.id_plan = A.id_plan
LEFT JOIN
    ".$this->config_vars["projects_user_table"]." AS C
ON
    C.id_project = B.id_project
WHERE
    C.id_project = '".$id."'
    && B.deleted = '0'
```

i think the problem is the COUNT (*) AS ...

how i can solve the problem?

Comment: Where form did you got 'B.deleted 'column and what is this && should be , maybe an 'AND' ?

Comment: @AgRizzo where i must place the group by?

Comment: At the end and before the HAVING and ORDER BY clauses (neither of which you have)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one, you are getting a record explicitly due to the COUNT().  Even though you have no records, you are asking the engine how many records which at worst case will return zero.  Count(), like other aggregates are anticipated to have a group by, so even though you don't have one, you are still asking.

So the engine is basically stating hey... there are no records, but I have to send you a record so you can get the count() column to look at and do with what you will.  So, it is doing what you asked.

Now, for the comment to the other question where you asked...

Yes but i want to count the project member from a project, how i can count the users from project_users where all users have the id_project 1.

Since you only care about a count, and not the specific WHO involved, you can get this result directly from the project_users table (which should have an index on both the ID_User and another on the ID_Project.  Then

```
select count(*) 
   from project_users
   where id_project = 1
```

To expand from basis of your original question to get the extra details, I would do...

```
select
      p.id_project,
      p.id_plan,
      p.name as projectName,
      p.description as projectDescription,
      pp.name as planName,
      pp.description as planDescription,
      pp.max_projects,
      pp.max_member,
      pp.max_filestorage,
      PJCnt.ProjectMemberCount
   from
      ( select id_project, 
               count(*) as ProjectMemberCount
           from 
              project_users
           where 
              id_project = 1 ) PJCnt
      JOIN Projects p
         on PJCnt.id_project = p.id_project
         JOIN Project_Plans PP
            on p.id_plan = pp.id_plan
```

Now, based on this layout of tables, a plan can have a max member count, but there is nothing indicating max members for the plan based on all projects, or max per SINGLE project.  So, if a plan allows for 20 people, can there be 20 people for 10 different projects under the same plan?  That's something only you would know the impact of... just something to consider what you are asking for.

Comment: Thanks! But how i can solve the problem? maybe with a second query?

Comment: @Evolutio, see revised answer.

Comment: can you start a chat, please? I have a few questiions about sql :)

Comment: @Evolutio, I created a chat at http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/50064/sqlhelpdvr?tab=general and join the room

Answer (score 0):

**Your cleaned-up query should look like :**

See sqlfidle demo as well : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e693f5/9

```
 SELECT
        A.id_plan,
        A.name AS plan_name,
        A.description AS plan_description,
        A.max_projects,
        A.max_member,
        A.max_filestorage,
        B.id_plan,
        B.name AS project_name,
        B.description AS project_description,
        C.id_user,
        C.id_project,
        COUNT(*) AS max_project_member
    FROM
        project_plans AS A
    LEFT JOIN
        projects AS B
    ON
        B.id_plan = A.id_plan
    LEFT JOIN
       project_users AS C
    ON
        C.id_project = B.id_project
    WHERE
        C.id_project = '".$id."';
```

---

This will return you `null` values for all the `cols` from the select because you have one legit return form the result set and that is the `count(*)` output `0`.
To fix this just add a `group by` at the end (see group by example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/14d46/2)  or 
Remove the `count(*)` and the null values will be gone as well as the count(*) values `0`

See simple sql example here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ab7dd/5

Just comment the count() and you fixed you null problem!

Comment: see my explain in the answer !

Comment: Yes but i want to count the project member from a project, how i can count the users from project_users where all users have the id_project 1 ?

Comment: use the 'group by' it will show the count if any result found !